# cpputest on STM8 failed due multiple 'main'

Tags: c++, c, cpputest, stm8

I want to use cpputest on STM8 and installed all the required tools for it.
I am able to run cpputest on my simplified code. 
on my main file which belongs to the hardware I have of course the main function. But in the Test environment I have a main function under AllTests.cpp as well. When I compile it i get the error:

```
multiple definition of `main'
```

A further issue I run into is: I compile the code for a 8bit processor and i use the library `<stdint.h>`, so my main file has the line `uint8_t main(){` . The compiler of cpputest does not like that at all...

Does anyone has an idea how to fix this?

Files:

blinky.h:

```
#ifndef BLINKY_H
#define BLINKY_H

#include "stm8l.h"
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t blink(void);

#endif
```

blinky.c

```
#include "blinky.h"


uint16_t blink(){
    PD_DDR = 0x1;
    PD_CR1 = 0x1;
    return 1;
}
uint8_t main() {
    // Configure pins
    while(1){
    // Loop
    blink();
    }
}
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "CppUTest/TestHarness.h"

extern "C"
{
#include "blinky.h"
}

TEST_GROUP(FirstTestGroup)
{
    void setup()
    {
    }

    void teardown()
    {
    }
};

TEST(FirstTestGroup, test1)
{
    LONGS_EQUAL(1, blink());
}
```

AllTest.cpp:

```
#include "CppUTest/CommandLineTestRunner.h"

int main(int ac, char** av)
{
    return CommandLineTestRunner::RunAllTests(ac, av);
}
```

Makefile:

```
#Set this to @ to keep the makefile quiet
SILENCE = @

#---- Outputs ----#
COMPONENT_NAME = blinky

#--- Inputs ----#
PROJECT_HOME_DIR = .
ifeq "$(CPPUTEST_HOME)" ""
    CPPUTEST_HOME = ~/tools/cpputest
endif

# --- SRC_FILES ---
# Use SRC_FILES to specifiy individual production
# code files.
# These files are compiled and put into the
# ProductionCode library and links with the test runner
SRC_FILES = src/blinky.c

# --- SRC_DIRS ---
# Use SRC_DIRS to specifiy production directories
# code files.
# These files are compiled and put into a the
# ProductionCode library and links with the test runner
SRC_DIRS = \
    platform

# --- TEST_SRC_FILES ---
# TEST_SRC_FILES specifies individual test files to build.  Test
# files are always included in the build and they
# pull in production code from the library
TEST_SRC_FILES = \

# --- TEST_SRC_DIRS ---
# Like TEST_SRC_FILES, but biulds everyting in the directory
TEST_SRC_DIRS = \
    tests \
    #tests/blinky \
    #tests/io-cppumock \
    #tests/exploding-fakes \
    #tests \
    #tests/example-fff \
    #tests/fff \
# --- MOCKS_SRC_DIRS ---
# MOCKS_SRC_DIRS specifies a directories where you can put your
# mocks, stubs and fakes.  You can also just put them
# in TEST_SRC_DIRS
MOCKS_SRC_DIRS = \

# Turn on CppUMock
CPPUTEST_USE_EXTENSIONS = Y

INCLUDE_DIRS =\
  .\
  $(CPPUTEST_HOME)/include/ \
  $(CPPUTEST_HOME)/include/Platforms/Gcc \
  platform \
  src \
  include \
  #example-fff \
  #test/exploding-fakes \
  #tests/fff


#STM8DIR

#SDCC_DIR :=$(CPPUTEST_HOME)/../sdcc/
#CC       :=@$(SDCC_DIR)/bin/sdcc
# --- CPPUTEST_OBJS_DIR ---
# if you have to use "../" to get to your source path
# the makefile will put the .o and .d files in surprising 
# places.
# To make up for each level of "../", add place holder 
# sub directories in CPPUTEST_OBJS_DIR
# each "../".  It is kind of a kludge, but it causes the
# .o and .d files to be put under objs.
# e.g. if you have "../../src", set to "test-objs/1/2"
# This is set no "../" in the source path.
CPPUTEST_OBJS_DIR = test-obj

CPPUTEST_LIB_DIR = test-lib
CPPUTEST_WARNINGFLAGS += -Wall
CPPUTEST_WARNINGFLAGS += -Werror
CPPUTEST_WARNINGFLAGS += -Wswitch-default
CPPUTEST_WARNINGFLAGS += -Wfatal-errors
CPPUTEST_CXXFLAGS = -Wno-c++14-compat
CPPUTEST_CFLAGS = -std=c99
CPPUTEST_CXXFLAGS += $(CPPUTEST_PLATFORM_CXXFLAGS)
CPPUTEST_CFLAGS += -Wno-missing-prototypes 
CPPUTEST_CXXFLAGS += -Wno-missing-variable-declarations
# --- LD_LIBRARIES -- Additional needed libraries can be added here.
# commented out example specifies math library
#LD_LIBRARIES += -lm

# Look at $(CPPUTEST_HOME)/build/MakefileWorker.mk for more controls

include $(CPPUTEST_HOME)/build/MakefileWorker.mk
```

Comment: You just cannot have 2 `main` functions, so you **have** to remove one of them. Using another names seems like one option. Putting the `blink()` function is a separate .c file is another.

Comment: But at least when I deploy it on my hardware I need to name it as main function, or do I get here something totally wrong?

Comment: Yes, you have to have exactly one `main` function in each build. So you might have to organize your files in a different way. Like splitting `blinky.c` into two files and only use one of those in the test build.

Comment: We put our firmware's main() src/main.c and our CppUTest's main() in test/AllTest.cpp. Then we have two build configurations, a "release" that builds the firmware and includes everything in src/ and another that's a "test" build configuration that excludes main.c but includes everything in test/ including AllTest.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the commends, there was no other way to create a file with the main loop for only the Controller and separate it from the unit tests.

My structure looks like:
main.c:
- contains the includes from the firmware (app.h) and the main() with the  run_app()
app.c: 
contains all the firmware and is tested with cpputest